# Pulling image from Amazon ECR from Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to pull a docker image from private Amazon Docker repository (ECR) from Bitbucket pipelines.

I'm doing the following:

```
script:           
   - aws ecr get-login --registry-ids $AWS_ID --no-include-email --region $AWS_REGION
   - docker run -d -p 9092:9092 --name=kapi $AWS_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/company/kapi:1.0
```

The error I see on Pipelines:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://$AWS_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/v2/company/kapi/manifests/1.0: no basic auth credentials.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the error seems pretty clear :

```
no basic auth credentials
```

**aws ecr get-login** return a command to execute in order to login. I don't know which platform do you use, but if your're using linux,

Try to execute the command returned by AWS:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --registry-ids $AWS_ID --no-include-email --region $AWS_REGION)
```

You should receive a message from docker that you are successfully logged in :

```
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
```

### Debug

You can still debug if it's still not working by running the command manually:

```
aws ecr get-login --registry-ids $AWS_ID --no-include-email --region $AWS_REGION
```

It should return something like :

```
docker login -u AWS -p ALongText https://ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The `aws ecr get-login` command generates a docker login command.  Unless you `eval` it, it won't actually log you in to the registry. This should work provided your `AWS_ACCESS_ID` and `AWS_ACCESS_SECRET` are correct:

```
eval $(aws ecr get-login --registry-ids $AWS_ID --no-include-email --region $AWS_REGION)
```

Your script step should look like:

```
script:           
   - aws ecr get-login --registry-ids $AWS_ID --no-include-email --region $AWS_REGION
   - docker run -d -p 9092:9092 --name=kapi $AWS_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/company/kapi:1.0
```